# Using the key of a computer that I connected to via SSH?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ssh-agent

I currently have a system where I'm using a desktop to connect to a gateway and then to multiple servers from there. The ssh key of my desktop is in the gateway and the other servers, and I'm running scripts from the desktop that use that connection, which have stuff like

```
ssh -A $GATEWAY "ssh $SERVER \"./myscript $OPTIONS\""
```

The problem is, when I connect from my home computer to the main desktop and use the same script, it tries using the ssh key of my home computer even if I don't use -A when connecting to the desktop. Is there a way of specifying which ssh key to use when doing the connnections?

I've tried doing

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -A $GATEWAY "ssh $SERVER \"./myscript $OPTIONS\""
```

but it still doesn't work. I'm not connecting to the main machine with -A, I'm just doing `ssh -i .ssh/loac_id_rsa user@main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's bizarre. Do you maybe have something in .ssh/config files?

Try executing

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

when arriving on your desktop

EDIT:

And if it does not try eval `ssh-agent -s` first.

Since that worked:

`-A` means "connect to auth agent". Your gateway certainly needs the auth agent to be running on your desktop in order to forward your connection to the protected host. The auth agent is probably launched automatically when you log in on your desktop with your graphical interface, but apparently when you log in using ssh it doesn't work like you want (it only takes your home key and ssh-add doesn't work). So you launch a new one and connect to it, add your key, and it works.

You could probably simplify a bit and replace

```
home$ ssh -i .ssh/loac_id_rsa user@main
desk$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
desk$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
desk$ ssh -A $GATEWAY "ssh $SERVER \"./myscript $OPTIONS\""
```

with

```
home$ ssh -i .ssh/loac_id_rsa user@main ssh-agent bash
desk$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
desk$ ssh -A $GATEWAY "ssh $SERVER \"./myscript $OPTIONS\""
```

or if you will be doing this regularly you could play around with the contents of `~/.ssh/rc` (be careful though since if you break something maybe you will not be able to log in over ssh, you'll have to repair by logging in on the console).

Comment: Thanks. `ssh-add` didn't work at first, but I did `eval \`ssh-agent -s\`` and now it's working.